# How to change vertex color and vertex size at the same time of Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, style

**How to change color and size at the same time of some vertices of a graph?**

I am trying to do it more than an hour but nothing seems to work.

I can do it either for color or for size but not both at the same time.

I want to have big blue disks.

```
HighlightGraph[GridGraph[{3, 3}], {1, 2}, VertexSize -> .2]
HighlightGraph[GridGraph[{3, 3}], Style[{1, 2}, Blue]]
```

[image]

[image]

This does not work:

```
HighlightGraph[GridGraph[{3, 3}], {1, 2}, VertexSize -> .2,Style[{1, 2}, Blue]]
```

Update:

Why the following code changes size of all vertices, I want to change size only of the green ones.

```
HighlightGraph[
 GridGraph[{3, 3}], {Style[PathGraph[{3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5}], 
   Red, Thickness[0.01]], Style[{3, 5}, Green]}, VertexSize -> 0.2]
```

[image]

Comment: With your last example, you are relying on the fact that `HighlightGraph` will interpret `VertexSize -> x` as wanting all highlighted vertices with size `x`.  You want more control than that, so use the more explicit form of that option:  `VertexSize -> {3 -> 0.2, 5 -> 0.2}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This input

```
HighlightGraph[GridGraph[{3, 3}], {1, 2}, VertexSize -> .2,Style[{1, 2}, Blue]]
```

is not valid syntax for [`HighlightGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightGraph.html).  `VertexSize` is an [`Option`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Option.html) and so it must come after all the other arguments

```
HighlightGraph[GridGraph[{3, 3}], Style[{1, 2}, Blue], 
 VertexSize -> .2]
```

[image]

Just for fun, here is another way you can modify properties of vertices and edges:

```
g = GridGraph[{3, 3}];
AnnotationValue[{g, {1, 2}}, VertexSize] = .2;
AnnotationValue[{g, {1, 2}}, VertexStyle] = Blue;
g
```

Comment: OK thanks, if you be so kind to answer additional question - see update. Why in your code the parameter changes only the two vertices and in my code all?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `VertexStyle` directives using `Style` ***and***

1. use the form `{Alternatives@@vlist1 -> optionvalue1, ...}` for setting the values of other `Vertex*` options:

```
HighlightGraph[GridGraph[{3, 3}], 
  {Style[PathGraph[{3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5}], Red, Thickness[0.01]], 
  Style[{3, 5}, Green, EdgeForm[{Purple, Opacity[1], Thickness[.02]}]]}, 
 VertexSize -> {3 | 5 -> .2, 1 -> .3},
 VertexShapeFunction -> {3 | 5 -> "Square", 1 -> "ConcaveHexagon"}, 
 VertexLabels -> {3 | 5 -> Placed["Name", Center]},
 VertexLabelStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

2. or use `Property[vlist, {options}]` (`Annotation[vlist, {options}]` in version 12.1+) to specify `Vertex*` options for `vlist`:

```
HighlightGraph[GridGraph[{3, 3}], 
 {Style[PathGraph[{3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5}], Red, Thickness[0.01]], 
  Property[Style[{3, 5}, Green, EdgeForm[{Opacity[1], Blue, Thickness[.02]}]], 
   {VertexSize -> 0.2, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    VertexShapeFunction -> "Hexagon"}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for very useful informations. In the Mathematica help you can find how to set different properties to all items but if you want to combine several properties to different items you have no examples in the help.